# The Imageview method setImageDrawable(Drawable d) doesn't change images with animation

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation, android-imageview, android-drawable

I want to change image in ImageView on button click.I am also doing animation on this imageView. For changing images i am using `setImageDrawable()` method on my imageView. The problem is that sometimes this method doesn't work for every image.Sometimes it changes the image and sets new image for ImageView but sometimes it doesn't change the image and shows nothing. If i debug my code then it shows all images. I don't know why it is happening because code is also not throwing any error.Is i am facing this problem due to memory ?

Here is my code :

```
public class AnimalsActivity extends Activity {

    private Animation animalTranslate;
    private ImageView animalImg;
    private static int cnt = 0;
    private ImageButton btnNext, btnPrev;

};

    private int[] animalImages = { R.drawable.antelope, R.drawable.bull,
            R.drawable.camel, R.drawable.deer, R.drawable.animal_elephant,
            R.drawable.fox, R.drawable.giraffe, R.drawable.animal_horse,
            R.drawable.iguana, R.drawable.jaguar, R.drawable.koala,
            R.drawable.animal_lion, R.drawable.monkey, R.drawable.nyala,
            R.drawable.orca, R.drawable.panda, R.drawable.quoll,
            R.drawable.animal_rabbit, R.drawable.snake, R.drawable.tiger,
            R.drawable.urial, R.drawable.vole, R.drawable.wolf,
            R.drawable.xerus, R.drawable.yak, R.drawable.animal_zebra };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.animal_screen);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_animalNext);
        btnPrev = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_animalPrev);
        animalImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animalImage);

        StartAnimations(cnt);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cnt++;
                if (cnt > 25) {
                    cnt = 0;
                }

                StartAnimations(cnt);
            }
        });

        btnPrev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cnt--;
                if (cnt < 0) {
                    cnt = 25;
                }

                StartAnimations(cnt);
            }
        });

    }

    private void StartAnimations(int count) {
            animalImg.setImageResource(animalImages[cnt]);
        animalTranslate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimalsActivity.this,
                R.drawable.letters_translate);
        animalImg.startAnimation(animalTranslate);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        cnt = 0;
        Intent readActivity = new Intent(AnimalsActivity.this,
                HomeScreenActivity.class);
        readActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(readActivity);
    }
}
```

Here is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lyt_animal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/forest"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/animalImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txt_animal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_animalPrev"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/animal_prev" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_animalNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/animal_next" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: your views are not getting refreshed so use `imageView.invalidate();` after setting it to a resource

Comment: i tried `invalidate()` but facing same problem.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I edited my code and now it is working. I guess, the error was due to lack of memory because i tested my application in emulator. I tested app in device and it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Starting animation from onCreate is not a good way. [Read this, It may help you.](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/08/start-animation-in-oncreate-or-onresume-on-android/)